# Resources inside root Java Dynamic web doesn't load ,JS Css

Tags: java, spring, jsp

While i'm tring yo include js file it's not working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I've tried also

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

[you can check the project structure as below pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOcf6.png)

And i have customized my view resolver to be, Does it will affect the path of resources !!

public class JstlView extends InternalResourceView{

```
@Override
 protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

 // Expose the model object as request attributes.
 exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(model,request);

 // Determine the path for the request dispatcher.
 String dispatcherPath = prepareForRendering(request, response);

 // set original view being asked for as a request parameter
 request.setAttribute("partial", dispatcherPath.substring(dispatcherPath.indexOf("Tasker/",1) + 1));

// force everything to be template.jsp
 RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp");
 requestDispatcher.include(request, response);

 }
```

Thanks alot ..

Answer (score 0):

It's just shot in the dark but did you try also:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried with the same result , please check the updates on post

Comment: All right, then can you check your .war file, that you have this js folder included? It should be some structure like this: https://imgur.com/OA3g0mr